# how to judge a paragraph in automatic abstract?

Tags: python

I am programming an automatic abstract algorithm with python.
Now I try to find the first sentence of each paragraph.So I have to divide each paragraph.
I came out with an idea that split the paragraph with newline symbols.For example,'\n'.
But it may not work each time.I am afraid the result vary from different platform.
Is there a better way to judge a paragraph?

Comment: perhaps indentation of the first sentence? Or sentences ending midway through the line? Or a blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good exercise in programs design. The style of paragraphs depends on the typographic conventions of the particular text. Some start with a new line, some with a space or tab indentation, some insert an empty line.

I you really want it to be an abstract (generic) algorithm, decouple that logic out of the main function and pass as an extra parameter, for example:

```
def split_by_newline(text):
    ''' Split text by new lines '''
    return text.splitlines()

def split_by_indentation(text):
    ''' Detect paragraphs by indentations '''
    # ...

def take_first_sencence(paragraph):
    ''' Expect a single paragraph, return its first sentence'''
    # ...

def take_first_sentences(text, paragraph_policy=split_by_newline):
    for paragraph in paragraph_policy(text):
        yield take_first_sentence(paragraph)
```

See also the [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). You won't need to worry about strange newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=[\r\n]))[^\r\n.]+\.?` will match all non-newline, non-dot characters after either the start of the string or a newline character with an optional dot at the end.